# Segmentation fault when stepping into a function defined in the same file using an ARM cross-toolchain

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, arm, gdb, qt-creator

I have this simplified example,

```
int myf(void) {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    return a + b;
}

int main(void) {
    int sum = myf();  // <--- bp here
    printf("Result: %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

I have a breakpoint at `int sum = myf()` and I run the debugger. Gdb successfully stops at this point, but a step into command (into `myf`) leads to a segmentation fault. If I put a bp directly in `myf` and run the debugger, then the debugger stops there as expected, no problem. In a shared library, not even the breakpoints work. They are ignored completely. Stepping into shared library code leads to the same segmentation fault error.

Step over functionality is also "broken". Stepping over code sometimes jumps into random (I think) locations, like in a file named `dl-minimal.c`

The code behaves as expected if it's simply run and not debugged.

Other useful info that I get in the debugger console when I get the segmentation fault error:

- No function contains specified address
- Disassembler failed: Cannot access memory at address 0xe7f001dc

See the printscreen for the full dbg console output:

[image]

The error is reproducible only when using a crosstoolchain for an ARM board (i.MX6). I have no such problem when debugging locally, on a Linux machine. I am using qtCreator 5.15. My cross-toolchain is built with yocto and bitbake.

Any hints regarding possible causes?

Comment: What compiler flags are you using to compile? Add `-O0 -ggdb3` and try that.

Comment: @cigien This would be the gist of it: -march=armv7-a -mthumb -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -c -pipe --sysroot=/home/mihai/toolchains/warrior/ces-fb-x86_64/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB

Comment: Is it an ARM cross-*debugger* as well?

Comment: Yes, it's "arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gdb". I think that's only a file name, though?! Running a --version on that gdb only says it's the GNU debugger, no mention of ARM or any other such thing.

Comment: @cigien I've added the flags you've specified. No luck. Same segmentation fault error.

Comment: @user253751, the "wrong debugger" issue came into my mind, as well. Should a debugger for a different arch actually be able to stop at breakpoints and displaying the local vars? Would it not complain when you actually started it with the given binary? Or what would one look after in such a scenario? What would be the hints that you're actually using a "wrong debugger"?

Comment: @mihai: Can you provide the complete output for `arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gdb --version` ?

Comment: @Frant, this is the output from a -gdb-version command (inside a gdb session): https://cutpaste.online/notes/2gXDLSQimj1CfW1F0u1S

Comment: @mihai: You may want to give a try to the GDB 8.3.0 which is part of the official `gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf` Arm toolchain available [here](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads). (or gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabi if your CPU does not have support for hardware floating point).

Comment: In Qt Creator, did you add the shared libraries into the GDB search path ? https://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/set_solib-search-path In Tools->Options->Debugger

Comment: @Frant, I have the GDB 9.1 version as well. This was the initial version which gave me headaches. It has the same behavior as stated in my question.

Comment: @Thalia, where exactly would that go? The shared library that I've tested with is actually part of the same project (as a sub-project). I would assume qtCreator knows how to find that?!

Comment: In "Additional Startup Commands"

Comment: My setup is something like `set solib-search-path /opt/eldk-5.3-vybrid/armv7a/rootfs-java-qte-sdk/usr/lib:lotsofpaths` `set sysroot /opt/eldk-5.3-vybrid/armv7a/rootfs-java-qte-sdk`

Comment: There I add any shared libs I want to step into. Another thing I must do, on the Options->Devices tab, I always must set the user that my application runs as. A bit annoying when I deploy as root... but hey, beats the alternative (command line)

Comment: @Thalia, sysroot seems to be set automatically by qtCreator when starting the debugger (according to the debugger log). Yes, I have the root user set in the Options->Devices. Should I try as a non-root user, maybe?! I do not get any warnings for solid-search-path nor for sysroot not being set. What error do you get if you don't manually set these?

Comment: The behavior you described is similar to putting breakpoints in a release build... Where I wrote "lotsofpaths" you should put YOUR absolute path to the debug build on the local machine. (separated by colon). And, as I said run as the normal user not root. You will have to keep switching the user, to be root when you deploy, and non-root when you run

Comment: @Thalia, you were right. Setting the correct sysroot solved it. I've had two sysroots in my generated toolchain, one for host (x86), and one for target(arm). The correct one seems to be the x86. Thanks so much for your suggestions! If you can find the time and the correct formatting of you comment as an answer, I will accepte it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the GDB search path - in `Tools->Options->Debugger`. In the `Additional Startup Commands` box. Place there the correct sysroot (corresponding to the platform you are running from), and follow with the full path of your shared libraries debug build, from the local machine.

Also, make sure to run as regular user (set in `Tools->Options->Devices`) - though you will need to switch to root user when you deploy.